# Encoding issues with PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have been searching and trying for hours and can't seem to find anything that actually solves my problem. 
I'm calling a PHP function that grabs content using the Google translate API and I'm passing a string to be translated. 
There are quite a few instances where the encoding is affected but I've done this before and it worked fine as far as I can remember.

Here's the code that calls that function:

```
$name = utf8_encode(mt($name));
```

And here's the actual function:

```
function mt($text) {

    $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=es';
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    echo curl_error($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      //Fetch the HTTP response code
    curl_close($handle);

    if($responseCode != 200) {
        $resultxt = 'failed!';
        return $resultxt;
    }
    else {
        $resultxt = $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
        return utf8_decode($resultxt);  //return($resultxt) won't work either
    }
}
```

What I end up getting is garbled characters for any accentuated character, like ***GuÃ­a del desarrollador de XML***
I've tried all combinations of encoding/decoding and I just can't get it to work...

Comment: Where are you seeing the garbled characters? In an HTML document?

Comment: I'm recording an XML file with the string that is returned from that function. I call the function multiple times, for each element of the XML file that I need to translate. I'm using SimpleXML - `$xml->asXML($xmlFile)`

Comment: I figured it out (partially). I'm working with XML files as stated above and it needed the encoding declaration as suggested by @gonzalon and had to use the following code to make it display corrrectly:
`$resultxt = $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
 $str = html_entity_decode($resultxt);
 $utf8 = utf8_decode($str);
return $utf8;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this kind of issues before, what I can tell you to try is:

1. In the `<head>` tag try to add:

`<meta http-equiv=”Content-type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″ />`

2. Try to add it in the `PHP` header:

`header(“Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8”);`

3. Check the encoding of your file, for example in the `Notepad ++`

Encoding > `UTF-8 without BOM`

4. Setting charset in the `.htaccess`

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

5. As you said you are reading files from the users you can use this function: [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to check for the encoding, and if it's different from `UTF-8` convert it. Try [this](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php#102382):

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. The problem is that I don't control which XML file gets loaded, they're user-generated files that may not contain the header. I've tried to add `charset=utf-8` in the PHP head and it doesn't work either...

Comment: I'll need to do more research but i created an .htaccess file with just that one line (is that all that's needed?) and placed in the same folder that the PHP file I'm loading and it didn't work. I never worked with .htaccess before...

Comment: Please see my update above. Adding the encoding info helped. The problem I still have is that I'm using user files and can't guarantee that they'll have encoding info and that it'll be UTF-8...

Comment: @PauloHgo check the update, you have to try to always convert the input to UTF-8

Comment: That solves my problem, thank you! I wasn't sure how to check for that.